# godep: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: heroku, go

I trying to deploy my server on heroku and I stuck on step where I should use godep, I spent little time with GO, last two days I had looking how to solve this issue, actually it's a popular issue, but I can't figure out, maybe I did something fundamentally wrong.

I have OS X 10.11.2
My GOPATH  - Users/denis/Programming/Golang
My PATH - $GOPATH/bin
I trying to use godep to my project which is placed in $GOPATH/src/backend

in my PATH I have an executable godep file(not .go).

Whole structure of my workplace.

```
/Golang/
     .bin/
        godep //executable file
     .pkg/
        .darwin-amd64/
             .//other folders/
     .src/
         .github.com/
         .backend/
         .//other folders//
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, what is the output of this:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

It should, at a minimal to run Go projects, have TWO directories in it for:

- /path/to/go/installation/bin (e.g. `/usr/local/go/bin`)
- /path/to/your/GOPATH/bin (e.g. `/Users/denis/Programming/Golang/bin`)

Your go's installation should be in your PATH already if you followed the Go installation setup.

https://golang.org/doc/install

Since you posted `/Users/denis/Programming/Golang`, with the capital `U`, I am going to assume that you are on OS X going forward...

In OS X, and if you used the default install, you can test for Go in your PATH with a simple command:

```
$ echo $PATH | grep --color=auto "/usr/local/go/bin"
```

It should print our your entire `$PATH` and highlight that you have things setup properly.  This is because the OS X GoLang installer in the URL above should have modified your PATH to include:

- `/usr/local/go/bin`
- or more specifically, it may be `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin"`

If you have some custom `.bashrc` and/or `.profile` files, then most likely your PATH isn't being setup correctly.  You can test this by doing this:

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin"
$ export PATH="$PATH:/Users/denis/Programming/Golang/bin"
$ godep go build
```

If it works now, then your PATH isn't setup properly in your .bashrc/.profile files.  That's a different kind of question and can be setup a 1000 different ways and you may need to figure it out (or another SO question).

If that resolves your issue, then you need to follow the `godep` directions to run `godep` from your project's root:

```
$ cd $GOPATH/src/backend/
$ godep save
$ git add Godeps/
```

`godep` creates a `Godeps` directory in the root of the Go project.  If you have multiple Go projects/multiple executables, then you need to run `godep save` on each root of the runtime.

IOW, for each executable you run `go build` for, you need to run `godep save` in each directory.

Also, once you move to `godep`, you want to use it for your build and testing as well:

```
$ godep go build
$ godep go test
...etc
```

If that's not the problem (you are running it as stated above), then please update your question with more specifics such as what `godep` command you are running, where, and what that directorys structure looks like for the root of that project (including the filename with `package main` and your `func main()` function).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have added two paths to my PATH variable(/usr/local/go/bin, $GOPATH/bin) and it works, but it generates empty Deps: [] block in .json, anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: make sure to run 'godep save' from within your project's root folder.